# d3.js failed to update data binding

Tags: d3.js

Absolutely newbie to d3.js

I am trying out a tutorial pull off from [internet](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/d3js/d3js_data_join.htm) which should be straight-foward but I am pulling my hair off now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>
        body {font-family: Arial;}
    </style>
    <body>
        <ul id="list">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <input type="button" name="load" value="Load List" onclick="javascript:load()"/>
        <input type="button" name="remove" value="Remove Fourth Value" onclick="javascript:remove()"/>
        <script>
            function load() {
                d3.select("#list").selectAll("li")
                .data([10,20,30,25,15])
                .text(function(d){console.log(d); return "This is pre-existing element and the value is " + d;})
                .enter()
                .append("li")
                .text(function(d){return "This is dynamically created element and the value is "+d;})
            }
            function remove() {
                d3.select("#list").selectAll("li")
                    .data([10,30,25,15])
                    .exit()
                    .remove()
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The HTML page will loaded with two empty pre-defined bullet points. The list will build after you click the "Load" button which is all fine. The logic I don't quite understand is on the "remove()" function which, by providing a new version of data, shouldn't d3.js remove the 2nd item on the list? Instead, it always remove the last item on the list as if the update is based on the size of the array passed to .data() instead of the actual values

In fact the original tutorial is not working as it described. But .exit() and .remove() should be comparing the existing data with the given new data and remove the one that is missed out in the new data?

Appreciate any help here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.data([10,30,25,15], d => d)`. For an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57048916/5768908